# Laravel - Chunk + Queue Jobs + DB::table()->insert freeze after 4000 jobs created

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I'm combine Queue Jobs, Chunk, and DB::insert.

I have 100.000 datas. (1 hundred thousand datas)

```
I have 2 jobs :
1. CreateChunkJobs >> Only 1 job, chunk 200 data...and dispatch ExecuteChunkJobs
2. ExecuteChunkJobs >> because chunk 200 data, so we have 5000 ExecutChunkJobs
```

Every Chunk have action to DB::insert.

But the problem here, i never get full 5000 jobs. I already retry 10 times, i only get around 3000 - 4000 jobs (loss almost half)

> I found something interesting is when i delete DB::insert, i always
> get 5000 jobs (correct number).

100.000 datas is come from DB::table('products') and DB::insert to another table called promos. Any idea why?

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: Unfortunately no. @apokryfos. Any clue is only when i comment/delete DB::table()->insert.. everything going well.

Comment: You need to share your actual code because we can't really know what might have happened with no code or any sort of error message